# How can I fix animated text to stay inside the 'LCD screen'?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm creating a typewriter effect with animation nodes and I've trouble with figure out how to make text stay inside the 'LCD screen' as I hoped text will stay inside the box but it kept typing over the box. I'm not really sure how can I fix this problem. I hope anyone can help out with this?

[image]

[image]

[image: Animation Nodes]

Comment: You can use the Boolean modifier to only show the text that intersects a another mesh i.e. a Cube the size of the screen.

Comment: I’ve tried with Boolean modifier but it didn’t work. I think it’s could be something to do with animation nodes?

Comment: How do you want the overflow to be handled? Do you want the text to scale down to fit? Do you want it to be cut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us say that your writer screen can display at most 20 characters, then we could trim the start of the text by subtracting 20 from the end as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Yes! That’s what I’m looked for. Thank you so much! You’re legend.

Comment: Omar, this is gold. Later, I will have new question about flexing text or making text jump. I will post a question in an hour or so.

Comment: @Odizm Please accept the answer if its answers your question.